# Update user control content

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, controls

I'm having a problem that seems really easy and yet I'm not finding any good posts about it,

so it's either more difficult than it seems,

or I'm using the wrong words when searching for it.

I'm adding User Controls inside a User Control, like this:

```
    public void CreateCard(Card card)
    {

        CardGUI cardGui = new CardGUI(card);

        cardGui.Size = new Size(71, 96);
        cardGui.Location = new Point(a, 50);
        cardGui.Show();
        a += 75;

        Controls.Add(cardGui);
    }
```

And this works in that it places them next to each other, but that's not my desired result, only something I did to be able to get some output to see.

> I want these smaller User Controls (Which represent cards in a deck)
>   to de able to overlap each other from left to right, and later ones
>   being the ones in-front, but my program is doing the opposite: the
>   later cards are behind the earlier cards.

So I'm wondering ***how I can get control of their z-index or get a similar effect***?

Also, **when I add a control and then remove it with a button, the image that the control contained doesn't disappear, leading me to believe the user control isn't updating it's graphics (something I have no clue about)**.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can call `cardGui.BringToFront()` or for more control, [SetChildIndex()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, BringToFront() solved it nicely for what I needed :)